# Detecting scroll direction - boolean variable wrong on first scroll change direction

Tags: jquery

I want to detect whether I am scrolling up or down. I also have a global variable which should be `true` if scrolling down and `false` if up.

The problem is, if I scroll down once, and keep scrolling down, the console logs `true` and `down`, but if I then scroll up just once, it logs 'up' correctly but also `true` instead of `false`. Same goes when scrolling the other way around.

So basically the `down` variable is wrong after first scroll change which changes direction.

```
<div id="id0" data-id="0" class="nbhd red scrolledto"></div>
<div id="id1" data-id="1" class="nbhd yellow"></div>
<div id="id2" data-id="2" class="nbhd green"></div>
<div id="id3" data-id="3" class="nbhd blue"></div>

var down = true;

    function setHeights() {
        $('.nbhd').css('height', window.innerHeight);
    }

    function scrollDirection() {
        var lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        $(window).scroll(function(event) {

            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (st > lastScrollTop){
                // down
                down = true;
                console.log('down');
            } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
                // up
                down = false;
                console.log('up');
            }

            lastScrollTop = st;

        });

        console.log(down);
    }

    setHeights();

    $( window ).on( "scroll", function() {
        scrollDirection();
    });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh3cgrqL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're hooking the scroll event **every time** anything scrolls, because you have this:

```
$( window ).on( "scroll", function() {
    scrollDirection();
});
```

...which calls `scrollDirection` every time there's any scrolling, and within `scrollDirection` you have this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

...which adds another handler. Each time. After a relatively small amount of scrolling the page will become sluggish and ultimately non-responsive as all those event hanlders stack up.

Separately, since `scrollDirection` is called repeatedly, your `lastScroll` is updated before the inner handlers have a chance to work with it.

Just hook up a single handler, and remember the last scroll position:

```
var lastScroll = 0;
var down = false;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    down = scroll > lastScroll;
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
(function() {
    var lastScroll = 0;
    var down = false;
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        down = scroll > lastScroll;
        lastScroll = scroll;
        $("#indicator").text(down ? "down" : "up");
    });
})();
```

```html
<div id="indicator" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0"><em>(No scroll yet)</em></div>
<div style="margin-top: 1.1em">
<div>
  scroll over this
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
  <br>.
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```